# SSL HandShake - Client Authentication

Tags: tomcat, ssl

How does a browser know which certificate to send to the server during client authentication step in ssl handshake when there are so many certificates with it. I mean how does it identify which certificate is for which server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now for CyberMonk's question

if you see my response above, you can see how the server is requesting the client to send a certificate with one of its trusted authorities. The client can pick a certificate based on this.

If there is a conflict, the browser's usually present you the list of certificates and ask you to pick one of these to use. I know that Safari and Chrome do this for sure.

Most likely, once you choose a certificate, the browser continues to use the same for the rest of the session.

Now, for you to make tomcat request the same, if this is a self signed certificate, you can place the public certificate in tomcat's truststore. It this is not a self signed certificate, you have to place the public root CA certificate in tomcat's trust store

A browser may contain several public certificates, but it won't send the certificate to a server unless it has the private key to sign it. You(or your browser) would have the private key only if  you went throughout he process of certificate creation. Once you have a private key and import the private key/public certificate pair into the browser, it will be able to send the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Client certificates aren't specific to a server.

Comment: oh if that's so, where do i place my client certificate in the browser. and if two different servers need two different client certificates how will a client pick the appropriate one. 
For ex: my tomcat users xml has a tag 

<role rolename="secureconn"/>
<user username="CN=localhost, OU=Software Solutions, O=xxConnection, L=Chennai, ST=Tamil Nadu, C=91" password="admin" roles="secureconn"/>

for which a certificate was installed in the clients browser with the same values. now how will the clients browser know that which certificate to pick when the handshake takes place

Answer (score 1):

The server can optionally send a list of required certificate agencies to the client. Then the client can pick the certificate signed by the required CA.

Comment: what if it's a self signed certificate? and how do i make my server (tomcat) tell that i want the browser to give me the certificate that i created using java keytool? So that i could validate it in the server's tomcat-user realm(I hope that is where we validate it!) am pretty new to the whole thing.

Comment: If the client certificate is self-signed there is no trust anchor you can offer, so it will probably not work. But maybe it will work if you have the expected client certificate in `trustStoreFile`. Apart from that I guess that tomcat just sends the names of all CAs it has in `truststoreFile` to the client, but I have no own experience with tomcat.